# how to repeat the same code (but slightly different each time) in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm working on a project, and one page has the same basic code over and over and I was wondering how to do this quicker than copy/pasting the code 721 times

```html
<div class="pokeFloat">
  <div class="pokeDec">
    <p>
      <img class="pokeImg" src="./img/pokeDex#.jpg" />
      <br>
      <small>PokeDex#</small>
      <br>pokemonName
      <br>
      <span class="typeA">TypeA</span class="TypeA"> - <span class="TypeB">TypeB</span class="TypeB">
 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each time i'd have to change pokeDex# (twice, once in the link the other in the text), pokemonName, and the two types, and it would be great if there was a quicker way to do this.

Comment: **P.S.:** You've have an error in your code: A closing tag (like `</span>`) couldn't have any attributies!

Comment: Do you use any JS frameworks?

Comment: Are you saying that you are currently copy, pasting and then changing this code all by hand? That you are looking for a way to save time when performing that (one-off?) task?

Comment: Presumably you have a list of the files. What format is that list currently in (flat text?, just files in a directory?)?

Comment: Either use a server side language (Like PHP) or use a javascript framework like AngularJS that allows you to loop over data (either from a data source or hard-coded values)

Comment: Angular JS is your best choice.. you can use ng-repeat over the 721 elements.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @aleberguer Angular is *a* choice, "best" is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merely target a parent container then use jQuery to create the amount of items you need. One line of HTML... then a jQuery loop to fill that container with everything else, 721 times.....

```js
var num = 721; //number of times you want definitions

for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    var theContent = $("<p></p>").html('<small>PokeDex #' + i + '</small> : <a href="/path/to/dex' + i +'">Dex ' + i + ' Link</a>'); 
         $('#pHolder').append(theContent);
     }
```

```css
p { background: #eee; margin: 10px; padding: 5px 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pHolder"></div>
```

vanilla Javascript (no jQuery)

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("pHolder"); //The holder
 var num = 721; //number of times you want definitions

for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
     var p = document.createElement('p');
     p.innerHTML = '<small>PokeDex #' + i + '</small> : <a href="/path/to/dex' + i +'">Dex ' + i + ' Link</a>';
  elem.appendChild(p);
     }
```

```css
p { background: #eee; margin: 10px; padding: 5px 10px; }
```

```html
    <div id="pHolder"></div>
```

[Fiddle with the div...](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/pk003827/)

Comment: I like this, however I'm not sure how is actually change the pokemonName and type values

Comment: @Skwarka kind of depends on where the data is coming from, if it's all manual input anyway... you could do a switch to iterate through an array containing the list of names and other individual data.. Not ideal, but much better than typing names manually. This was just to show you *how*. I wasn't expecting it to be a direct copy/paste solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't use a serve-side technology, or something that compiles to html as Haml, and you want to use javascript and html... with a little help of jquery so you don´t have reinvent the wheel....

One solution would be to hide the html that you use as template. Then, using jquery (or other library or vanilla javascript) grab it as a string, do the replacements, and then insert the resulting string as html into the dom.

Here is a quick example with just three iterations. You will need to populate the specific data of each repetition. I use a list of objects, as the data.

If I were you I would use a library like Knockout, Angular, or Mustache.

```js
// Data of each iteration
var data = [
  {name: 'Pikachu', dex: 'pikachuDex', typeA: 'pikachuA', typeB: 'pikachuB'},
  {name: 'Charmander', dex: 'charmanderDex', typeA: 'charmanderA', typeB: 'charmanderB'},
  {name: 'Ratata', dex: 'ratataDex', typeA: 'ratataA', typeB: 'ratataB'}
];
  
// Get the template
var template = $(".pokeFloat").html();

// Iterate over data, customize template, append to html
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var str = template.replace(/typeA/gi, data[i].typeA);
  str = str.replace(/typeB/gi, data[i].typeB);
  str = str.replace(/pokemonName/gi, data[i].name);
  str = str.replace(/pokeDex/gi, data[i].dex);
  
  $("#list_of_pokemones").append(str)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pokeFloat" style="display: none">
      <div class="pokeDec">
        <p>
          <img class="pokeImg" src="./img/pokeDex#.jpg" />
          <br>
          <small>PokeDex#</small>
          <br>pokemonName
          <br>
          <span class="typeA">TypeA</span class="TypeA"> - <span class="TypeB">TypeB</span class="TypeB">
     </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="list_of_pokemones">
</div>
```

Please, note that I hid the template using `display: none`, and added a new `div` as placeholder for the dynamically generated html.

It is not the best solution, but should give you an idea about how to do it.

Comment: Do not iterate arrays with `for...in`, do not parse HTML with regex, etc.

Comment: @Oriol will you be so kind to explain why I shouldn't?

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630) and [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: @oriol About the for..in, I get your point, but in this context is the same. Anyway, I fixed that. But about regex, I agree that there are better options, but beside performance, I don't see how it could be a problem in this particular example. Besides, my idea is to be a guide about how to think the problem. If you would like to pinpoint a problem, a bigger one is that my solution does not clone the root node, only the inner html.